# IO.inspect printing list or map twice

Tags: elixir

Is printing two versions of a list or map the default behavior for `IO.inspect`

Example, below operation will print two separate lists.

Here is the output on the console:

```
[
  ok: %{
    "code" => "a",
    "id" => "1"
  },
  ok: %{
    "code" => "b",
    "id" => "2"
  },
 ...
 ...
]
[
  ok: %{
    "code" => "a",
    "id" => "1"
  },
  ok: %{
    "code" => "b",
    "id" => "2"
  },
]
```

Why is it doing this? The second list that is in the output is in a different font color on in the terminal. Not sure if that is an indication of something.

```
  def parse_csv do
    @csv_path
    |> Path.expand(__DIR__)
    |> File.stream!
    |> CSV.decode(headers: true)
    |> Enum.into([])
    |> IO.inspect
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ran the code in iex, then the first list you saw is printed by `IO.inspect`, and the second list is the return value.

If you run `IO.inspect(1)` in iex, you'll see `1` twice, because `IO.inspect` always returns the first argument, and iex always prints the return value of the expression you type in.

Comment: `iex` always prints the **inspected** return value of the expression.

Comment: I am actually calling my function with `iex` and forgot to add in the `inspect` at the end of my pipeline, but still same behavior. Is it supposed to be like this when I call function `parse_csv ` in `iex` terminal?

Comment: @henhen No. If you don't add the `IO.inspect` at the end, you just get one printing of the map, the one printed by iex from the return value of `parse_csv`.